# Update table gives primary key violation error

Tags: sql-server, database, join

I have following tow tables

```
create table #temp(id int,rid int)
insert into #temp
select 1,1
union all
select 2,1
union all
select 3,1

select * from #temp

drop table #temp1
create table #temp1(id int, nid int,PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
id asc,nid asc
))

insert into #temp1
select 1,10
union all
select 2,10
union all
select 2,11
union all
select 3,10
```

Following are the both result sets:

```
id  rid
1   1
2   1
3   1

id  nid
1   10
2   10
2   11
3   10
```

I want to update #temp1 table with value from rid field of #temp table by matching id field from both tables. See following query:

```
select a.*
from #temp1 a inner join #temp b
on a.id = b.id
where a.id <> b.rid
```

It returns:

```
id  nid
2   10
2   11
3   10
```

I want to update id with following query:

```
update a
set a.id = b.rid
-- select a.*
from #temp1 a inner join #temp b
on a.id = b.id
where a.id <> b.rid
```

But it returns

> primary key violation error because of primary key in table #temp1.

I would like to delete the value if it is already exist if not then I would like to update

for example 
id nid 
1 10 
2 10-- want to update but not able to this bcoz it violates primary key so delete this row. 
2 11-- able to update this row but other 2 rows causing an issue.
3 10-- want to update but not able to this bcoz it violates primary key so delete this row.

Please suggest other ways to do this.

Comment: Don't do it - the primary key must have been put on there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Because You are Violating the `Primary Key Constraints`

Check Below Tables

```
select B.*
from #temp1 a inner join #temp b
on a.id = b.id
where a.id <> b.rid

id rid
2   1
2   1
3   1



select * from #temp1

id   nid
1   10
2   10
2   11
3   10
```

You are setting ID of above first table using join from #temp which already in #temp1

**You Are attempt to Update Values which are already in #temp1 where id=2,2,3**

Comment: Yes I would like to delete the value if it is already exist if not then I would like to update

for example

id nid
1 10
2 10-- want to update but not able to this bcoz it violates primary key so delete this
2 11-- want to update able to do this but issue is other 2 rows.
3 10-- want to update but not able to this bcoz it violates primary key so delete this

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from #temp1 a inner join #temp b
on a.id = b.id
where a.id <> b.rid
```

You would be updating two id 2 records to the same value. You cannot do this, period. There is no other method to fix this except to drop the PK which I would suggest would be bad idea.

It is possible you need some further definition in your  pdate to specify which of multiple records you want to update or you may need to delete the record which might end up as a duplicate before you do the update. Not knowing the business rules for what you are actually trying to accomplish or what your data means, it is impossiblet say what you can do to solve your problem. This ia case where the solution is dependant on the meaning and of course we have no meaning here.

Comment: Yes I would like to delete the value if it is already exist if not then I would like to update

for example

id nid
1 10
2 10-- want to update but not able to this bcoz it violates primary key so delete this
2 11-- want to update able to do this but issue is other 2 rows.
3 10-- want to update but not able to this bcoz it violates primary key so delete this